# Security Exception - The application attempted to perform an operation not allowed by the security policy

Tags: openid, dotnetopenauth

I have a simple implementation where I instantiate OpenIdRelyingParty and then call RedirectToProvider.  It runs fine in a hosted environment at 1and1 and also on Cassini (Visual Studio 2010).  However, when I deploy it onto the IIS on my PC (Windows 7), I get a Security Exception:

> "*The application attempted to perform an operation not allowed by the security policy.  To grant this application the required permission please contact your system administrator or change the application's trust level in the configuration file*."

somewhere in the following code:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e) 
{ 
    string realm = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Realm"]; 
    Uri returnPath = new Uri(new Uri(realm), "welcome.aspx"); 
    using (OpenIdRelyingParty openId = new OpenIdRelyingParty()) 
    { 
        IAuthenticationRequest request = openId.CreateRequest("https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id", 
              new DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.Realm(realm), returnPath); 
        request.RedirectToProvider(); 
    } 
}
```

The error message is cryptic and the knowledgebase articles on rectifying it are even more so.

- Who is attempting to perform what operation?
- What is DotNetOpenAuth trying to access?
- Who or what is not trusting who?
- What is the security policy it is talking about?
- What is in that policy?
- Where can I find it or change it?

Thanks.

---

May 2, 2012

As requested, here is the call stack:

```
[SecurityException: Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.ReflectionPermission, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.]
System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.ThrowSecurityException(Assembly asm, PermissionSet granted, PermissionSet refused, RuntimeMethodHandle rmh, SecurityAction action, Object demand, IPermission permThatFailed) +150
System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.ThrowSecurityException(Object assemblyOrString, PermissionSet granted, PermissionSet refused, RuntimeMethodHandle rmh, SecurityAction action, Object demand, IPermission permThatFailed) +100
System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.CheckSetHelper(PermissionSet grants, PermissionSet refused, PermissionSet demands, RuntimeMethodHandle rmh, Object assemblyOrString, SecurityAction action, Boolean throwException) +283
System.Security.PermissionSetTriple.CheckSetDemand(PermissionSet demandSet, PermissionSet& alteredDemandset, RuntimeMethodHandle rmh) +69
System.Security.PermissionListSet.CheckSetDemand(PermissionSet pset, RuntimeMethodHandle rmh) +150
System.Security.PermissionListSet.DemandFlagsOrGrantSet(Int32 flags, PermissionSet grantSet) +30
System.Threading.CompressedStack.DemandFlagsOrGrantSet(Int32 flags, PermissionSet grantSet) +40
System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.ReflectionTargetDemandHelper(Int32 permission, PermissionSet targetGrant, CompressedStack securityContext) +123
System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.ReflectionTargetDemandHelper(Int32 permission, PermissionSet targetGrant) +54
```

Comment: A callstack for the exception would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely it's the outbound HTTP request that OpenID must make to log users in.  If your web.config file sets up the site to run under medium trust, try bumping it to high or full trust.

The reason medium trust works in hosted environments but not "at home" is because the default medium trust configuration that ships with ASP.NET does not allow outbound HTTP requests, but most shared hosting environments modify this setting so that medium trust allows it.

At home, the easiest way to solve it is to raise the trust level in your web.config file.

Comment: weird.  I've not seen that before then.